# How to compile Kotlin code to jvmTarget="1.8" for tests

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, junit5

In our Android project we code in Kotlin and target java 1.6. However we are forced to java 1.8 in our test since some JUnit5 features requires it (static methods in interfaces).

Is it possibe to compile the tests differently than the production code?

We tried to raise the jvmTarget to 1.8 by adding this to our build.gradle:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
}
```

This raises the jvmTarget of the production code too, but we only want it for our tests.  The [Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options) indicate that it can be specified for the test like this:

```
compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin{
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Unfortunatly the `build.gradle` doesn't compile.

Comment: Maybe try `compileTestKotlin` instead of `compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin`?

Comment: How did you force Java to be 1.8 for tests only?

Answer (score 4):

The Kotlin docs mention [how to do](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options) it for tests only.

Groovy DSL:

```
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Kotlin DSL:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks

compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet does the job for me:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    if (it.name.contains("UnitTest")) {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
        }
    }
}
```

I have to say, It's not the best solution to filter the test tasks based on their names, so think of this as a quick and dirty aid.